# Add variable inside a variable?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the best method to perform string concatination in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311272/which-is-the-best-method-to-perform-string-concatination-in-php)

I tried to add a variable and string to another variable like this:

```
finalData += $ajaxData + 'some text';
```

To no avail. The result is nothing. Any advice? Thanks

**EDIT: I made a major mistake! I forgot I was working with Jquery! It was a long day guys sorry! :)**

Mods please delete question.

Comment: your mixing js syntax with php

Comment: i can almost hear people typing answers

Comment: I made a major mistake! I forgot I was working with Jquery! It was a long day guys sorry! :)

Comment: Can you show what finalData and $ajaxData contains?

Comment: Hi wirey. I am so tired I didn't realize I was working with jquery and not php. I figured it out :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string concatenation in php is done with a `.` so you need to do:

```
$finalData .= $ajaxData . 'some text';
```

Comment: I made a major mistake! I forgot I was working with Jquery! It was a long day guys sorry! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
finalData += ajaxData +'some text';
```

Comment: I made a major mistake! I forgot I was working with Jquery! It was a long day guys sorry! :)